# Testing Email locally? Could i reroute email to watchdog?

Tags: 6, ubercart, emails, testing

I'm trying to debug how an email invoice looks in ubercart locally. Mail is not configured on my local machine (ubuntu 11.10).

I really would prefer to debug this locally without sending nagging emails to the stakeholders.

Is there anyway to reroute email output to the watchdog log?

Comment: Found this as a good resource as well for D7: http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/oh-no-my-laptop-just-sent-notifications-10000-users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Maillog / Mail Developer](http://drupal.org/project/maillog) module.

> Maillog provides an easy possibility to log all Mails for debugging purposes. It's possible to prevent the mails to being sent, so there is no need for an extra mail server to test the mail functionality of other modules or the Drupal core. Additionally you can immediately display the mail through the devel `dpm()` facility.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

It will listen to port 25 and save emails to files and optionally open them in your local email client